# can not print item from json file with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Can anybody help me with this problem?

My code:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:  
    r107sData = json.load(f)  

for r107s in r107sData:  

    print(r107s['feedback'][0])
```

Json Schema:

https://pastebin.com/CBEy8hUG

Error;

'''
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "api.py", line 39, in 
        print(r107s['feedback'][0])
    KeyError: 0

**Thanks friends!** 
**i've solved the problem**

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully, your json is a list or an array. The dictionary element comes inside of it. You'd instead do `r107s['feedback']` like -

```
import json
with open('tmp.txt', 'r') as f:
    r107sData = json.load(f)

for r107s in r107sData:
    print(r107s['feedback'])
```

Output:

```
{'sos_signal': 'S0s Signal'}
{'goodfeedback': 'Good feedback'}
{'badfeedback': 'Bad feedback'}
{'sos_signal': 'S0s Signal'}
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me .. ''' Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(r107s[0]['feedback'])
KeyError: 0

Comment: Yes now it's working but i can see only last one. I need to get all feedbacks in json file and calculate how many good or how many bad feedback are there

Comment: Have you posted only a part of the json? If yes then post the whole json.

Comment: i've edited my question. you can see whole json under my question

Comment: Are you even trying? I just copy pasted your whole json and ran it with the code in my answer and it outputted - ```{'sos_signal': 'S0s Signal'}
{'goodfeedback': 'Good feedback'}
{'badfeedback': 'Bad feedback'}
{'sos_signal': 'S0s Signal'}```. What more do you need?

Answer (score 0):

`0` does not exist as a key in your `r107s['feedback']` dict, but `sos_signal` does.

If `r107s['feedback']` was a list, then `r107s['feedback'][0]` would give you the first element.

So `r107s['feedback']['sos_signal']` will give you `"sos"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use "sos_signal"

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json


with open('sample.json', 'r') as f:
    r107sData = json.load(f)

for r107s in r107sData:

    print(r107s['feedback']['sos_signal'])
```

Please note my json file name is bit different